# Tensorflow reading and writing to BigQuery

Tags: tensorflow, google-bigquery

I can't find an example of writing data to BigQuery using Tensorflow. So far I got the following,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import json_format
from tensorflow.contrib.cloud.python.ops.bigquery_reader_ops import BigQueryReader


PROJECT=...
DATASET=...
TABLE=...
TIME=0
NUM_PARTITIONS=5


graph = tf.Graph()
sess  = tf.Session(graph=graph)
with graph.as_default():
    features = {"ts": tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.float32),
                "v":  tf.FixedLenFeature([5], tf.float32),
                "m":  tf.FixedLenFeature([2, 3], tf.float32)}

    reader = BigQueryReader(project_id=PROJECT,
                            dataset_id=DATASET,
                            table_id=TABLE,
                            timestamp_millis=TIME,
                            num_partitions=NUM_PARTITIONS,
                            features=features)
    queue = tf.FIFOQueue(100, [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32],
                         shapes=[[1], [5], [2,3]])
    key, value = reader.read(queue)
    enq = queue.enqueue([[1.0], [2.0]*5, [[3.0]*3]*2])
    print "Going to run!"
    sess.run(enq)
```

I am unfamiliar with the syntax for readers. Although this doesn't give me errors, it also doesn't insert data into the database.

Could you please give me an example of using BigQuery with Tensorflow?

Comment: How did you post your question to flipper?

Comment: What's flipper?

Comment: I meant "flipboard", I found your question there https://flipboard.com/topic/programming/tensorflow-reading-and-writing-to-bigquery/f-5bbee71c86%2Fstackoverflow.com  I guess they skim the internet like google?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `BigqueryReader` which *reads* data from Bigquery, it does not write data, and no such writer exists.

I'm assuming you want to write data into a Bigquery table so that you can read it out for a training job, why does this need to be done in TensorFlow? I can't think of a use case in which you'd need to write data to Bigquery from TensorFlow.

Comment: It would need to be done in Tensorflow for my particular system. We want to train and then run inference results back into BigQuery.

Comment: Just use a scalable inference server (either cloud.google.com/ml/docs or roll your own with github.com/tensorflow/serving ) and provide a proxy that writes out the results to Bigquery. No need to do this from TF.

Comment: Also consider Apache Beam/Google Cloud Dataflow: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-prediction-example. You could load a saved model and predict in distributed batches. And with Tensorflow Transform, you can normalize data in the training phase.

Answer (score 2):

Now, you can load a TensorFlow saved model directly into BigQuery:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL advdata.txtclass_tf
OPTIONS (model_type='tensorflow',
         model_path='gs://cloud-training-demos/txtclass/export/exporter/1549825580/*')
```

Then call ML.PREDICT to carry out predictions:

```
SELECT *
FROM ML.PREDICT(MODEL advdata.txtclass_tf, 
               (SELECT * FROM input_data))
```

See this article for details: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-do-batch-predictions-of-tensorflow-models-directly-in-bigquery-ffa843ebdba6